# Messy system with Langrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> $f(x,y) = (3-x)(3-y)(x+y-3)$

I'm trying to find and classify the critical points of the former function. I have that

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (3-y)(-x^2-xy+2x+3) \\\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = (3-x)(-y^2-xy+2y+3)$$

Then both partial derivatives are zero for $(0,0)$ because of the first term of each one.

Now, if we add up the second term of both partial derivatives and multiply the result by $-1$ we have

$$x^2+y^2-2x-2y=0 \equiv (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-2=0$$

To find extrema in the last circumference I'm using Lagrange multipliers.

Let $g(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-2=0$. Then taking $L(x,y)=f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)$ and its partial derivatives within the system

$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0\\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0 \\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} =0\end{cases}$$

I have

$$\begin{cases} x^2+xy^2-5xy-3x^2+6x-3y+9=2x\lambda+2\lambda\\ x^2+xy^2-5xy-3y^2+6x-3x+9=2y\lambda+2\lambda \\ (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-2=0\end{cases}$$

Here is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to solve this system. Since the first and second equation are alike, if I subtract them I get $3(y^2-x^2)+3(y-x)+2\lambda(y-x)=0$, but I don't see how this helps me to get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a hard question

A common technique is to find the x,y restrictions for equations 1 and 2 to be equal to later be used in equation 3 to find actual values of x and y. A great way to do this is by manipulating dg(x) and dg(y) so that dg(x) = dg(y) and so then df(x) = df(y) and from there find restrictions.

$$dg(x) = 2\lambda x+2\lambda$$ $$df(x) = dg(x)$$

Knowing:
$$ df(x) = \lambda 2(x+1) $$ $$df(y) = \lambda 2(y+1)$$
You multiply dg(x) by what dg(y) has that dg(x) doesn't and vise versa to make them equal.

thus.. $$ dg(x)(y+1) = dg(y)(x+1)$$ $$ \lambda 2(x+1)(y+1) = \lambda 2(y+1)(x+1)$$
and $$\lambda (y+1)df(x) = \lambda (x+1)df(y)$$ (multiply by lambda to include lambdas effect on the restriction)

$$\lambda (y+1)(x^2+xy^2-5xy-3x^2+6x-3y+9) = \lambda (x+1)(x^2+xy^2-5xy-3y^2+6x-3x+9)$$
Now after lots of painful algebra:
$$\lambda ((33y-13y^2+y^3+2xy^2)-(33x-13x^2+x^3+2x^2y)) = 0$$ $$ \lambda \not= 0 $$ $$ 33y-13y^2+y^3+2xy^2 == 33x-13x^2+x^3+2x^2y $$
from this $$ y = x $$
now into equation 3 $$ (x-1)^2+(x-1)^2 = 2 $$ $$ 2(x-1)^2 = 2 $$
$$ (x-1)^2 = 1 = x^2-2x+1 $$ $$ x(x-2) = 0$$ 
From this, critical points at x = 0 y = 0 and x = 2 y = 2

Max f(2, 2) = 1

Min f(0, 0) = -27

Confirmed by wolfram alpha